# How to hide query parameter from URL in Apache Configuration?

Tags: apache

I'm trying to hide the query parameter from the URL so is there any way to do that? However, till now I'm able to find that we can use post but I am unable to find configuration for it
Getting:
"https://example.com/page.php?Page_ID=1234"
Want:
"https://example.com/page.php"

Comment: Alternatively, how do you plan to navigate between page 1234 and 1235?

Comment: I don't know can you please suggest something?

Comment: You can't do anything in Apache's configuration against what your application sends.